# Using member function without taking address?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

```cpp
class C{
public:
  int i(){return 3;}
};

void memfn(int (C::* const & func)()){}
void fn(int (* const & func)()){}

int main() {
  fn(&foo); //Works
  fn(foo); //Works
  memfn(&C::i); //Works
  memfn(C::i); //Doesn't Work
}
```

When passing a function pointer as a parameter, the address-of operator is optional on the function. Why does it not work if removed on a member function?

Comment: Because that's the rules of the language. There is a [special rule for functions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.func) but no corresponding special rule for member functions.

Comment: The rule that allows the name of a function to be converted to a pointer (so you don't need the `&`) is actually an exception in the language.  What you say about member functions is actually the "normal" and being able to remove the `&` on non-member functions is the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion from global function references, or static member function references, or non-capturing lambdas, to function pointers. This is for capability with C.

But such implicit reference-to-pointer conversions are not for non-static member functions (and capturing lambdas!), because they need an implicitly passed `this` pointer to work, the conversion just lacks that thing.

In your case, if we make `i()` static, then it can be passed to `fn` either by reference or by address.